# passing parameter from one batch apex into another batch apex

Tags: batch

I want to know whether it is practically possible to pass a parameter from first batch apex into second batch apex. I do not want code but a brief concept would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you simply pass the values to the next batch, typically in the constructor.

```
public class Batch1 implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
  Integer veryImportantValue;
  public Batch1(Integer someParam) {
    veryImportantValue = someParam;
  }
  // omitting start and execute
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    Database.executeBatch(new Batch2(veryImportantValue));
  }
}
```

The first batch would be called with the parameter:

```
Database.executeBatch(new Batch1(42));
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. I have one doubt, do we need to sue database.stateful to maintain the state of across transactions?

Comment: @PoojaBiswas Anything you set before start method runs will be available in the finish method without Database.Stateful. This will improve performance. You only need to use Database.Stateful if you need to modify the variables during the execute method.

Comment: thanks, there's one more thing I would like to ask, its a separate topic. I hope u dont mind. what is Test.isRunningTest() method used for. how can I use this in batch apex and callout?

Comment: @PoojaBiswas You shouldn't use Test.isRunningTest for callouts usually. You should be able to test it with just Test.setMock.

Comment: can we use Test.isRunningTes() to check of first batch has completed and then start the second ?

Comment: @PoojaBiswas You can't run more than one batch per unit test using Test.stopTest, so you'll have to have multiple unit tests.

Comment: Think you need `Database.Stateful` to carry the field value across to the `finish` method.

Comment: @KeithC Read [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm). Too long for a comment, but when you don't use Database.Stateful, variables that are set before start method remain set, but cannot be modified, between each call to execute. They include some example code.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, didn't know that (and should have read the earlier comment more carefully).